# Were there any top Nazi generals who opposed the idea to invade the USSR?

Tags: world-war-two

Did any one of the top Wehrmacht generals, who was a war-monger and agreed with Hitler's doctrine of expansion by force, ever attempt to dissuade him from the idea to invade the USSR in principle (not just postpone attacking until some conditions are met)? If yes, what was his (their) vision on how to continue the German war campaign that had been so successful?

I presume Hitler's top generals were not accustomed to vehemently oppose his decisions. However, it does not mean some of them could not try to persuade him to abandon some specific idea. Given the vast territory and impressive human resources of the Soviets, going into war with them was very risky business after all.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97731/discussion-on-question-by-s-n-were-there-any-top-nazi-generals-who-opposed-the).

Comment: Are you asking about Generals who didn't want to invade the USSR at all, or those who opposed operation Barbarossa specificly ?

Comment: According to this (sourced) reddit post: https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/3v18ps/did_hitlers_top_generals_realize_that_operation/ Erich Raeder would be a candidate.

Comment: Many (most/all?) high-ranking generals of the Wehrmacht in WW2 participated in WW1 in some way. WW1 ended badly for Germany, as the two-front war turned out to put too much strain on Germany. The WW1 and post-WW1 experience had a strong influence on the decision makers at the time. So, Hitler's plan to invade the Soviet Union was definitely a tough sell.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### There were quite a few people in high positions who were opposed to war against USSR

[Erich Raeder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erich_Raeder) as a head of the Kriegsmarine opposed war against the Soviet Union [before the defeat of Great Britain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erich_Raeder_during_World_War_II#Sea_Lion_and_the_%22Mediterranean_plan%22). We could take this as a professional deformation, because at the time Britain was a great naval power and effectively blockaded Germany just like they did in WW1. In Raeder's professional opinion, in 1941 Germany should have executed the so called Mediterranean plan, and eliminate British presence in North Africa and Malta, capture Gibraltar etc... and then choke Britain out of the war by cutting off traffic of strategic materials to the island. Only after that war against the Soviet Union should be considered, especially since US started giving more and more help to British, therefore there was a limited window of opportunity to do this.

[Hermann Göring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_G%C3%B6ring) as the head of Luftwaffe, was also ["strongly opposed"](https://books.google.rs/books?id=su07xExJPIAC&pg=PA128&lpg=PA128&dq=Hermann%20G%C3%B6ring%20opposed%20invasion%20of%20soviet%20union&source=bl&ots=_MWPgmmrPw&sig=ACfU3U05jB2PD56k3G9LjePbe63QLodG8g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjN9ufhyZfkAhVjysQBHXMGDukQ6AEwEXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=Hermann%20G%C3%B6ring%20opposed%20invasion%20of%20soviet%20union&f=false) to war vs the Soviet Union, again because his air force left an unfinished job with Britain, and because RAF now gradually grabbed air superiority over France and started night raids against Germany itself. He was not alone with this opinion in the Luftwaffe, generals like [Erhard Milch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erhard_Milch) and [Otto Hoffmann von Waldau](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_Hoffmann_von_Waldau) also doubted that the Soviet Union could be defeated completely before the onset of the dreaded Russian winter.

[Joachim von Ribbentrop](http://Joachim%20von%20Ribbentrop). although not a military leader, as a Foreign Minister of the Third Reich opposed the war vs Soviet Union. He may have had personal reasons as the [Molotov–Ribbentrop Pact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molotov%E2%80%93Ribbentrop_Pact) was a crown achievement of his career, and by his opinion gave Germany the chance to fight Britain "with both hands", chance that Hitler now squandered. It is said that Ribbentrop personally respected and even admired Stalin, so this could be another reason for his opposition against war.

Finally, it must be said that German army generals ([Heer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_Army_(1935%E2%80%931945))) wholeheartedly supported Hitler's ideas of conquest, including [chief of staff Halder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franz_Halder) and field-marshals like [Walther von Brauchitsch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walther_von_Brauchitsch). This again could be professional deformation, because land conquest of Russia was a feat that none had achieved for centuries, and they felt themselves invincible after France. However, there were cooler heads even among them. One example would be [Ernst August Köstring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_August_K%C3%B6string). Köstring served as a military attaché in Moscow, and argued that [even capture of Moscow would not knock USSR out of the war](https://history.army.mil/html/books/104/104-21/cmhPub_104-21.pdf), as Soviets had industrial capacities beyond Ural and could reorganize their transport network.

Comment: The phrase "*professional deformation*" makes no sense in either usage, and I am unable to discern or guess your intent. Please explain so the phrase can be corrected.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens [Professional deformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9formation_professionnelle), or job conditioning, is the concept that professional training and experience affects one's worldview and judgement. In the scope of this answer, it means that Raeder saw gaining dominance on seas more important than securing borders on land, while Heer commanders shifted their priorities off of Britain as soon as it was forced out of ground combat in Europe.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Career naval officer like Raeder was naturally more concerned about naval powers (i.e. Britain) then about land powers (USSR) . Danila explained it nicely .

Comment: I think there should a difference being made between those who opposed Operation Barbarossa *at that point in time* and those who opposed it *on general terms*. The (now archived-to-chat) comments on the original question outlined a necessity to make that distinction. To my knowledge, virtually all who opposed the war against the USSR opposed the *schedule* (i.e., logistics), not the war per se (i.e. the geostrategic decision).

Comment: @DevSolar Yup. And the Q still reads "idea". As this 'idea' was already very popular in Reichswehr times, this A reads quite misleading to me. No sources here to support the 'generals opposed to that war goal in general'. The Goering citation even ever more emphasising timing, not fundamental disagreement… Unless this A provides evidence for the prosaic parts, that need disentanglement anyway, I'd say it is not correct.

Comment: I think I did not express myself clearly indeed. So let me clarify. I have little doubt there were people (military generals amongst them) who opposed the idea of such invasion until Britain could be neutralised. It is just logical.

Comment: Actually, I was more interesting to know the names of generals who objected to this course of war (attacking the USSR) in principle, for «They are very strong, they have enormous material and human resources, they can sustain heavy losses and we can easily end up losing the war completely, especially if the USA will genuinely support them» (after all this is what really happened).

Comment: And offered something in stead. For example, «Let's strangle Britain, conquer the remaining neutral European countries, reorganise and germanise all of Europe and increase our naval power to be able to send considerable expedition forces overseas to deal with the USA». As @DevSolar pointed out such idea certainly was not on Hitler's mind. I am sure he is right and it was not. But it does not mean no one could think of it.

Comment: @S.N. Please edit your clarifications into the question, don't post them in comments. Neither below the Q, nor in chat, nor below answers.

Comment: @S.N. I don't think there was a German officer at that time who would say "We should not attack USSR under any circumstances" . But since Germany and USSR were not alone in the world, there was quite a number of those who argued that USSR should not be attacked until such and such preconditions are met . If Hitler listened their advice war with USSR would practically never happen, because those preconditions could not be met .

Comment: @LangLangC Done.